# Empty Search Results in Haystack Solr Django (Getting Output with prefix u in Django Shell)

Tags: django, solr, django-haystack

**Getting results in shell but “No results found.” (On the web page)**

**What i use is :**

Start a Django shell (./manage.py shell)

```
from haystack.query import SearchQuerySet
sqs = SearchQuerySet().all()
sqs.count() // get back an integer > 0 (Output is 1800)
```

But when i use

```
sqs[0].text

Result is : u"[u'PALMER SECOND BAPTIST CHURCH\\nPALMER\\n']"
```

*An extra u"[u' as a prefix appears in my output !*

*I think because of this my Search Results is Empty*

Already Follow https://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/latest/debugging.html for Debugging

**Thanks in Advance** for any help to solve this issue

Comment: It sounds like you got a result back and that you got 1800 results in total. Exactly why do you think you didn't get a result? And please don't open a new question to add more details.

Comment: Thanks for reply but i am not getting any search results : i think because of prefix u

Comment: The prefix u is a Python identifier saying that the string is a unicode string. I'd look at the Solr side to see what you've actually indexed (and if it's a `str()` representation of a list with strings. If you didn't get any hits, you wouldn't have a count of 1800 or get a result with `.text` at all. Why do you think you're not getting a hit when both these indicate that you do?

Comment: MatsLindh is correct.  You have results.  I would bank on you having submitted string representations of a string list to your indexing engine

Comment: @MatsLindh  getting results in shell but not in Django templets

Comment: @SNTiwari so you have to share your templates and `views.py` file to check what's wrong with your service.